# FFT frequency is always half of expected

Tags: fft, sampling

I think I have a bug in my understanding of the complex FFT and it's leading me to get half of my expected frequency.

I'm trying to calculate the frequency of an input signal of known frequency (440Hz) using the FFT. My sampling rate is 8kHz, which is well above the Nyquist rate, and I'm using an analog filter with a knee at 4kHz. I toggle a pin on each sample and measure with the oscilloscope, so I know it's sampling at 8kHz. (maybe I am wrong there?)

EDIT:
I have the same results for triangular, square, and sinusoidal inputs.  They are created by a 555-Timer and are completely positive (ranging from 0-5V) with a DC offset of around 2.5.  Here is an example of the (more-or-less) triangular input (after sampling):

> {"2560", "2C00", "3390", "3970", "4000", "4610", "4C30", "51A0", \
>   "5700", "5C70", "61D0", "65E0", "6BD0", "70A0", "7500", "7980", \
>   "7DF0", "7FF0", "78C0", "6860", "59E0", "4BC0", "3FE0", "3370", \
>   "2880", "1E10", "1450", "0AA0", "0230", "01B0", "0A50", "1200", \
>   "1A10", "2140", "28A0", "2F50", "3650", "3C40", "4300", "4870", \
>   "4EC0", "5400", "59B0", "5EF0", "6400", "6900", "6DF0", "72A0", \
>   "7720", "7B70", "7FC0", "7FF0", "7130", "61A0", "53A0", "46A0", \
>   "3A30", "2E80", "23B0", "1950", "0FE0", "06E0", "FE50", "0540", \
>   "0D80", "1590", "1D30", "2480", "2BA0", "3230", "3900", "3ED0", \
>   "4550", "4B60", "5130", "5650", "5C20", "6100", "65D0", "6B30", \
>   "6FE0", "7480", "7910", "7D30", "7FF0", "7AD0", "6AD0", "5BC0", \
>   "4E30", "4170", "34F0", "29C0", "1F50", "1550", "0BF0", "0370", \
>   "0040", "08E0", "1150", "18B0", "2020", "2780", "2E30", "3530", \
>   "3B40", "4190", "47B0", "4DA0", "5370", "58C0", "5E20", "62D0", \
>   "6910", "6CD0", "74C0", "7650", "7B30", "7EA0", "7FF0", "73F0", \
>   "6470", "5600", "47F0", "3BD0", "3000", "2530", "1B30", "1120", \
>   "08B0", "FFD0", "04C0", "0C80", "1490", "1C40", "2340", "2A70", \
>   "3140", "3760", "3E10", "4470", "4A20", "4FF0", "55F0", "5B70", \
>   "6000", "65B0", "6AA0", "6F00", "7410", "7820", "7CF0", "7FF0", \
>   "7DF0", "6D00", "5E20", "5030", "4340", "3680", "2B80", "20F0", \
>   "1740", "0D80", "04F0", "FC70", "0780", "0FB0", "17B0", "1F40", \
>   "2650", "2D30", "3410", "3A60", "4100", "46F0", "4CD0", "5290", \
>   "5860", "5D10", "6300", "6790", "6C80", "7200", "75F0", "7A40", \
>   "7EC0", "7FF0", "75D0", "6640", "57B0", "4A60", "3D80", "30B0", \
>   "22E0", "1CA0", "12D0", "09F0", "0120", "0290", "0B40", "1350", \
>   "1B40", "2230", "2970", "3000", "3700", "3D70", "4360", "4940", \
>   "4F50", "5490", "5A40", "5F70", "64B0", "69C0", "6EB0", "72F0", \
>   "77C0", "7BD0", "7FF0", "7FF0", "6FC0", "60B0", "52A0", "4550", \
>   "3930", "2D90", "22C0", "18A0", "0F50", "0640", "FE00", "0600", \
>   "0E60", "1600", "1DD0", "2510", "2C20", "3270", "3970", "3F80", \
>   "45B0", "4B90", "5170", "56C0", "5C80", "61A0", "66A0", "6B80", \
>   "70A0", "74D0", "7960", "7DA0", "7FF0", "7900", "69A0", "5A70"}

[image: Triangular input after normalizing to 1.]

I set a breakpoint after the ADC has collected all 256 points, and when I graph it one cycle takes around 17 points **(ACTUALLY 33)**. Each point is 1/8000=.000125s, so one period is **.004125** , which gives me **242Hz**. Not perfect, but also not the cause of my problem. **(Edited: I read the period incorrectly.  Therefore, the FFT data is correct, but the sampling only gets either half the data or is somehow sampling too slowly.  Any ideas?)**

If I run an FFT on these datapoints in Mathematica, I get that the 8th bin has the greatest magnitude, which would give a frequency of 8*(8000/256) = 250Hz and half of what I expect. (well, more than half, but the frequency resolution is about 31.25 Hz/bin)

I take the 256 data points and plug them into the first half of a 256-point fractional complex array in the microcontroller. Then I reorder the data so that they are every other point in the array, and fill in 0's for the complex values. Then I run the FFT from the Microchip library and also get bin 8.

Am I using the complex FFT or the bin number incorrectly? If so, could someone please explain where I'm going astray?

EDIT: The following picture is referenced in a comment to Peter K's answer.
[image: Complex_DFT_visual]

Comment: Is your input a pure Sinusoid? Can you share your input signal?

Comment: Are you reading two channels on oscilloscope? One I and one Q, only then you are working with a complex input. Otherwise it is just real valued signal and will not give the expected.

Comment: @Oliver I added the input.

Comment: @learner I and Q on the oscilloscope?  From all that I've read, one can add all the data into the real values and set all the complex values to 0.  Should I use the Real FFT instead?

Comment: In your plot, I can't see a period of 17 points. Apart from that strange artifact at around index 60, I'd say the period is about 30, i.e. a fundamental frequency of about 267 Hz.

Comment: Hm... @MattL. you're correct about that.  Now I'm not sure if I reran my program between the og post and adding the graphic, but when given the above input, Mathematica is correct.  I'll rerun the program on the uC and get fresh values from the ADC.

Comment: Yes, that was the correct ADC data, so I guess it's a sampling problem.  The waveform looks correct, however.  Any ideas?  When I increase the timer that triggers the ADC, the period is increased, as expected.  Is there a known issue that would explain the the half sample frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake.  I was toggling the pin at 8kHz, which means the sample rate was double that of the pin oscillations. (pin high + pin low = 2 samples, but one pin period.) The FFT and ADC config except the sample rate were actually correct the whole time.

Thank you for all the help.  Unfortunately, I have too few reputation points to give anybody an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this calculation:

> 8*(8000/256)

If the bin number is 8, then the frequency of that bin will be `8*(8000/128)`.

Why? Because the maximum frequency that sampling at 8kHz can show (without aliasing) is 4kHz.  So the bin at about `N/2` (where `N` is the number of points in your FFT) will correspond to half the sampling frequency...

The bin at `N=256` will correspond to a frequency of `-8000/256`.

Comment: Using the pic of the ComDFT that I added to my question, if the Re and Im arrays are each N=256 and they are processed IN PLACE, then after the FFT the first 128 elements of each will contain the magnitudes, and these are then squared, summed to the respective element in the complementary array, then rooted to find the 128 magnitudes.  So now I have 256 total values, but only the first 128 are useful (because the second half contains the neg freq.)  Is that right?  Then the last usable value (N/2) should correspond to 4k.  Then shouldn't each bin be 4000/128? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think that's right, the FFT bins extend up to the sampling frequency, because you could have complex-valued data with no symmetry in the frequency domain. See also [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16015/what-is-normalized-frequency-in-the-range-0-1-%C3%A0-la-dtmf-goertzel-algorith/16017#16017).

Comment: @MattL. Which is not right? What PeterK. said or my comment?  The trouble I'm having here is deciding what exactly N is in the bin calculation _fi = i*fs/N_ since it seems to change in the Complex FFT.  The image gives the impression that the Freq domain actually gives 8k at the 128th element (**N/2**), which would align with PeterK's answer and explain my error.  Is it correct though?

Comment: @MrUser: My comment referred to Peter's answer. $N$ is the FFT length, i.e. the number of time domain points over which you compute the sum, which is the same as the number of frequency bins you get. For real-valued time-domain data the frequency bins are symmetric, so you can throw away (approximately) half of them.

Comment: @MattL. So you're saying that N/2 (128th element) of the frequency arrays should be 4k, and each bin frequency is 8000/256, not 8k with each bin having a density of 8000/128? The N doesn't somehow "change" in the complex DFT, right?  (I only say that, because in this case N in the pic above could also just refer to the array size.)

Comment: @MattL. Um, I don't see it as a complex **signal** the question refers to a complex **FFT** (which they all are?). And the OP's update to the question clarifies: the signal is real-valued, not complex.

Comment: @PeterK. There's actually a real FFT.  And I think MattL. said that the complex FFT allows for complex input ("could have complex-valued data"), which would eliminate the symmetry in the frequency domain that one sees with "real-valued, time-domain data."

Comment: @PeterK.: I didn't mean to say that the data are complex-valued, but the FFT doesn't care about real-valued or not; for $N$ time domain points you get $N$ frequency bins extending up to $f_s$, where for real-valued data half of them can be discarded due to symmetry. What I'm saying is that $f_i=i\cdot f_s/N$, $i=0,1,\ldots,N-1$ irrespective of whether the data are real or complex.

Comment: @MrUser: Yes, the bin at index $N/2$ corresponds to Nyquist, if $N$ is the FFT length, i.e. the number of points in your vector that is being transformed.

Comment: @MattL. So you're saying that the $f_N = f_s$ ? That seems wrong in that it implies you can sample a signal at 8kHz and be able to see all frequencies up to and including 8kHz. That doesn't work for real-valued signals... unless you're doing bandpass sampling, which the OP is not (they explicitly state ` I'm using an analog filter with a knee at 4kHz. `).

Comment: @PeterK.: Well, yes, but it doesn't imply anything funny about the sampling theorem. The frequencies higher than Nyquist are just the periodic continuation of the negative frequencies, which for real-valued signals are the complex conjugate values of the positive frequencies. If you take the FFT of a sinusoid on the FFT grid, don't you also get two spikes, one at bin $k$ (whatever that is), and one at $N-k$, which is between Nyquist and $f_s$ (or, if you like, the negative frequency component)?

Comment: @MattL. : Right! I tend not to think about frequencies outside of $[-f_s/2, +f_s/2]$ when dealing with sampled data.

Comment: @PeterK.: You don't even need to: the interval $[-f_s/2,0)$ is just shifted up to $[f_2/2,f_s)$; that's why some smart guy invented `fftshift()`.

Comment: @MattL. I know. Your statement about FFT results returning content at $f_s$ though is very confusing!